# how to open HTML page in a part of aspx page

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a Aspx page it is divided in sections.In a section a need to open a html page. please provide me some solution.Also i need to pass some data to the loading html page

Thanks in advance....!

Comment: Look into iframe or jquery.load

Comment: use uframe http://uframe.codeplex.com/

Comment: Adil & Sridhar : Architect has prohibited use of UpdatePanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an iFrame to do this. An iFrame is used to embed another document within the current HTML document. To pass data, query strings would be sufficient.

```
<iframe src="http://www.YourPage.com/Path/to/file.aspx?info1=Hello&Info2=World">
</iframe>
```

If you want to show the content for a user event (click, change, blur etc), then it would be nice to use `jQuery.load` function which loads the the html page using javaScript (ie. ajax).

Comment: Can you brief me about passing data in query string from aspx page and retrieving data from Query string in HTML page.

Comment: Read this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString

Comment: This is simple to accomplish. However, you may not need this approach to do it. Your requirement could be satisfied with user controls or similar approaches. You need to use iFrame only when the two pages are  hosted differently.

Comment: i need to retrieve data in html page. the solution what you provided is in code behind. i have tried the responce.getParameter(ParameterName) . but it does not return any value